# Change appearance of combobox when is focused

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I change the appearance of a combobox when it receives focus?
The combobox is not editable and would have to stay looking like that when you receive the focus:

https://magnusmontin.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/combobox.png?w=525&h=143

Here's the code:

http://pastebin.com/yej92T14

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Please post the minimum amount of your code necessary to reproduce the problem. In general, people will not follow links to read your code. Also, your question will become useless once the links break (and links _always_ break).

Comment: I did follow the link, but the triggers don't involve anything with focus.

Comment: Philip, i need insert a trigger for focus, but i don't how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success!

I create a new ControlTemplate with a yellow color and i changed in the event IsFocused

Here's the solution:

```
<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
    <Setter TargetName="ToggleButton" Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButtonFundo}" />
</Trigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your control template triggers:

```
 <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
         <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
         <!-- Change appearance here -->                   
 </Trigger>
```

This will make it red on focus (with line 2)

Comment: Not worked RedLaser.
The combobox is not editable. The appearance not changed.

Comment: @RodrigoGazola comboboxes are not meant to be editable from the users view.  Either edit it in code or change how you are doing it

Comment: In your example, how i change the appearance of the combobox?

Comment: @RodrigoGazola changed above code to something that should work now (forgot the targetname part originally)

Comment: i changed the above code and don't worked:
<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
</Trigger>
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @RodrigoGazola You need the target name as well as per my last edit